# centering a third party menu

Tags: css, menu, header, center

I'm having much problems with my header.

I'm using joomla 2.5 and I've installed maximenuck for the header, but I can't center it at screen.

You can see my web here: http://www.barataweb.es/lourdes/.

Comment: Can't see the site, I just get a ´Internal Server Error´.

Comment: In the future, post the relevant code here in stead of linking to an external page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

......................
......
Hi now used to this css

```
   #header ul.menu.maximenuck {
        margin-top: 44px;
        position: static;
        width: 1000px;
    }
```

your navigation define is `position absolute` than first you change to `position` and now define your `navi` `min width` than apply **css** according to your design

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code may help you

```
.maximenuck{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

paste this code in your .css file and check it weather its center or not.

Comment: Hi Selva! Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve the problem...I have tested everything without luck :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're doing something wierd with the placement (#wrapper2, #main)

You cannot center it, even using Selva's answer, because the ul has **position:absolute**. Change it to relative, then apply Selva's values.

Comment: Hi Marius! Thanks for your reply :) What Rohit tells solved it! Regards